# Converting a List into ListNode

Tags: python, list, linked-list, int

I am answering a question on LeetCode and I am having a hard time understanding how to code LinkedList (or ListNodes) in Python. I understand the concept of a LinkedList but I still can't understand how to convert a list of integers into a LinkedList of the same!

I've already tried reading some information on this stuff online and I see there are some recursive options available, but recursion is v.v.costly and I'm not a huge fan of it. Below is LeetCode's implementation of a LinkedList and my way of converting a list into a LinkedList

```py
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.next = None

list1 = [4,5,1,2,0,4]
head = ListNode(list1[0])
e = 1
while e < len(list1):
      print(head)
      head.next = ListNode(list1[e])
      head = head.next
      e+=1
return head
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are missing the reference to the head of your list, because you are overwriting it. Start with this instead:

```
list1 = [4,5,1,2,0,4]
head = ListNode(list1[0])
tail = head
```

Then `tail` will be a reference to the last element of the linked list. Now in your loop you do:

```
while e < len(list1):
      print(head)
      tail.next = ListNode(list1[e])
      tail = tail.next
      e+=1
```

So you add an element to the list as before, but now we are modifying the `tail` variable. At the end:

```
return head
```

You will now be returning the head node of the list.